# How can i do server side Sorting in JSGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I have implemented jsGrid and did the Filtering server side.Now i want to send sorting parameter to server side and do the sorting on server side on the click of column.
This is how i implemented the grid -

```
 var db = {

  loadData: function(filter) {
    var bFilter = [];
    var d = $.Deferred();
    console.log("sorting:", filter.sortField, filter.sortOrder);
    for (var prop in filter) {
      if (prop != "sortField" && prop != "sortOrder") {
        bFilter.push({
          "Name": prop,
          "Value": filter[prop]
        })
      } else{
       var sorting ={ "Name": filter["sortField"], "Type": filter["sortOrder"] };
      }
    }

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://abc/abc",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "filter": bFilter,
          "sorting": sorting
        })
      }).done(function(response) {
        d.resolve(response.value);
      });

    return d.promise();

    },

    };


    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    height: 300,
    width: "100%",

  filtering: true,
  editing: true,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload: true,

  pageSize: 2,
  pageButtonCount: 5,

  deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

  controller: db,

  fields: [{
      name: "Name",
      type: "text",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      name: "Age",
      type: "number",
      width: 50
    },
    {
      name: "Address",
      type: "text",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      type: "control"
    }
  ]
});
```

How would i call the same loaddata method on click of header for sorting to do the filtering and sorting together on server side.
How to disable the client side sorting and do it on serve side same like filtering.
If i set `sorting:false` it removes the click from the column headers.I want to keep that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the sort function -

```js
jsGrid.loadStrategies.DirectLoadingStrategy.prototype.sort = function () {
    var filters = $("#tableId").jsGrid("getFilter");
    var sorting = $("#tableId").jsGrid("getSorting");
    this._grid.controller.loadData(filters, sorting);
}
```